# ios iphone hooks open instagram directly without showing UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, instagram, uidocumentinteraction, uidocument

I'm integrating sharing images through instagram in my app. I've read their [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/#).

It seems that I need to use the iOS UIDocumentInteractionController to allow this (I understand that it allows access to files in my app's sandbox).

Digging deeper, I came across this [library](https://github.com/mglagola/MGInstagram) which makes things very straightforward.

The problem I have with it is that it presents the action sheet (which only has one button - Instagram...) How can I use the instagram hooks , with the UIDocumentInteractionController without showing the action sheet. I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523475/instagram-open-uti-directly) which is pretty much the same, but its outdated with no answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've searched for this myself, I don't think it's possible to use the UIDocumentInteractionController without showing an action sheet, nor does it seem possible to share an image with instagram without using a UIDocumentInteractionController.

Which leads to the unavoidable action sheet.

I understand why they designed it like that (you won't leave an app unknowingly as a user) but it leads to annoying UI design in many cases.

Comment: Check Shots app. They do it without UIDocumentInteractionController. I wonder how..

Comment: The app "10" shares without an action sheet. That's what got me searching on this topic.

Answer (score 7):

I use a very simple share-open Instagram flow.

- I save image **locally** to photos
- Then I open Instagram with following URL: **instagram://library?AssetPath=assets-library**

This opens Instagram **directly into photos library**. Because photo was saved few moments ago, the new photo is visible as the first photo in library.

Comment: man.. that's brilliant !

I thought that was a way to open photo library instead of camera but this is even betten for sharing single photos.

Well.. if you got an URI to open photolibrary i take it as well ^^

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this method is **NOT** mentioned in the [Instagram documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/#ios-developers). However, I just confirmed that [@sabiland's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34765800/7245977) answer still works in Swift 4.2 iOS 12. Here is some sample code:

```
func postImageToInstagram(image: UIImage) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(self.image(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

@objc func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let err = error {
        print(err)
    }

    let urlString = "instagram://library?AssetPath=assets-library"

    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Instagram is not installed", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[Original code source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38550605/7245977)

You also have to make sure you `info.plist` has the instagram query scheme.

> In order for your app to use Instagram's custom URL scheme, you mush whitelist the scheme by adding instagram:// to the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key in your app's Info.plist.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/#ios-developers)

[image: info.plist]

Comment: Just switched my app to using this method after the old way of using Instagram hooks via the share sheet stopped working properly in iOS 13. This is a much cleaner and nicer method too!