# Share on Instagram/WhatsApp without UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios7, share, instagram

Is there any way to share an UIImage to Instagram and WhatsApp without using UIDocumentInteractionController?

I want to set a button for IG that won't open the OpenIn menu, and won't make me select an app from the menu.

Same goes for Whatsapp...

Or perhaps a way to use UIDocumentInteractionController but somehow setting the selected app to be (for example) Instagram without prompting the user to choose IG app from the OpenIn menu.

Thanks in advance

Haim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to share an image without UIDocumentInteractionController. Perhaps Whatsapp or Instagram will provide an API for this in the future.

Comment: This is wrong. Here is a confirmed way to bypass the showing of the menu and open Instagram right away: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34765800/3344977